# Newsstand register for push notifications issue

Tags: ios

Im using the following code to register for push notifications for a Newsstand app.

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability];
```

It calls didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and i get a device token. When i log enabledRemoteNotificationTypes it returns 0 and didReceiveRemoteNotification is never called.

It works fine if i register with UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert enabledRemoteNotificationTypes returns 4 and i get the notifications.

I have added the required background mode in the plist.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I've solved the issue. It was an iPad store setting that was turned off.